# storing image to byte[] into Mysql using asp.net and c#

Tags: mysql, image, arrays, blob, store

I am using `Asp.net with C#` and back-end `MySql` to keep `Images as byte[] array` with using `BLOB datatype`

`TABLE : ImageLog`

```
ImgID                 int (auto increment)
ImageLogo             blob
```

I am using following `function to convert image to array...`

```
private byte[] ConvertImageToByteArray(FileUpload fuImgToByte)
    {
        byte[] ImageByteArray;
        try
        {
            MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(fuImgToByte.FileBytes);
            ImageByteArray = ms.ToArray();
            return ImageByteArray;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

here is calling method for creating `byte[] bt` to insert into `MySql`

```
Byte[] bt = null;
bt = ConvertImageToByteArray(FileUploader1); --> Passing File Uploader ControlID
```

inserting like...

`INSERT INTO IMAGELOG (ImageLogo) VALUES ('"+bt+"')`;

Now, Program runs perfectlly without causing any errors but when image stored into MySql, `it stored like System.Byte[] not into byte[] array`. Result Something like this...

```
ImgID      ImageLogo
________________________________
  1        System.Byte[]    13K ( Length )  < ----- > not storing byte[] in proper format
  2        System.Byte[]    13K ( Length )
```

Please tell me is it in proper format ? ? or not ?? Every suggestions are welcome.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem Solved After Lot's of Difficulties... Simply Add Parameters With `?` instead passing byte array `bt` directly within Insert Query...Something like this:

`INSERT INTO IMAGELOG (ImageLogo) VALUES (?p1)` and Pass values something like this

cmd.Parameters.Add("?p1", bt); <-- Adding parameter p1 value here

Note: If you are using `MySql` as database end then i suggest to use `?` instead `@` symbol.

`OUTPUT:`

```
ImgID      ImageLogo
________________________________
  1        Binary Image    73K ( Length ) < ----- > You can see the difference...
  2        Binary Image    69K ( Length )
```

Hope It Helps You All, Chears. !!