# Saving Byte[] Array to MYSQL

Tags: c#, mysql, arrays

Possibly Answered Here:
   [storing image to byte[] into Mysql using asp.net and c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12805015/storing-image-to-byte-into-mysql-using-asp-net-and-c-sharp)

```
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Imaging;

var imageBytes = imageToByteArray(pictureBox1.Image);     

var insert = new MySqlCommand("Insert INTO itemimage set imageName = '" + imageBytes + "'", _con);

insert.ExecuteNonQuery();   


public byte[] imageToByteArray(Image imageIn)
{
    var ms = new MemoryStream();
    imageIn.Save(ms, ImageFormat.Gif);
    return ms.ToArray();
}
```

---

```
Table: itemimage
2 | System.Byte[]  | 13byte    

3 | System.Byte[]  | 13byte
```

What is wrong with this code? thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> What is wrong with this code?

You're using string concatenation to form the SQL. That's calling `ToString` on a byte array, which gives `System.Byte[]` as the result.

Instead, use a parameterized query, and set the parameter value to your byte array.

Something like this:

```
var data = ImageToByteArray(pictureBox.Image);
using (var cmd = new MySqlCommand("INSERT INTO itemimage SET imageName = @image",
                                  _con))
{
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@image", MySqlDbType.Blob).Value = data;
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Mind you, I'm a bit concerned about the column name here - is it really meant to be the *name* of an image (which is what the column name suggests) or the *data* in an image (which is what your code suggests)? Those are two very different things, and you should make it clear which is which.

You should *always* use parameterized queries:

- They prevent [SQL injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com)
- They reduce data conversion issues
- They separate the code from the data more cleanly

Comment: Can you do an example code sir Jon, sorry noob here. Thanks for your consideration.

Comment: right now I got: (Binary/Image). Once again, thank you for being generous with your example. Now I can understand more. I hope this could also help other people like me. Good Day.!

Comment: Yeah for sure. Got the same issue. Same solution worked. Upvoted. Thanks for this a lot! :)