# How do i upload images using a form using Spring, Thymleaf and MySQL to my application?

Tags: java, html, mysql, spring, thymeleaf

So i have a products model where my user can add different products to the database using a basic form.
I want the ability for them to also add an image while adding the product details.
Im struggling to find a solution and most of the resources i see are using hardcoded images or other frameworks such as angular.

Currently when i save the product, my POST method gets skipped because my image file is NULL for some reason.

I know there are other ways to store an image on the server side but i want to store it to my database.

Thanks in advance!!

Heres my code

1. Product Model

=======================

```
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "product")
 public class Product {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(name = "product_id")
private long id;

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumn(name = "Category", referencedColumnName = "product_category_id")
private Category category;

@Column(name = "product_name")
private String name;

@Column(name = "product_description")
private String desc;

@Column(name = "product_quanitity")
private int quantity;

@Column(name = "product_price")
private double price;


@Column(name = "file")
@Lob
private byte[] file;


// Getters/Setters
}
```

2. Product Controller related methods

=======================

```
   @Controller

   public class ProductController implements Serializable {

   private ProductRepository productRepository;


   public ProductController(ProductRepository productRepository) {
    this.productRepository = productRepository;
    };


   @Autowired
   ProductRepository service;

   @Autowired
   CategoryRepository serviceCat;

   @Autowired
   private UserRepository userRepository;



   @GetMapping("/addProduct")
   public String showSignUpForm(SessionStatus sessionStatus, Category category, Model model) 
   {




     List<Category>list = (List<Category>) serviceCat.findAll();

         model.addAttribute("list",serviceCat.findAll());


     return "addProduct";
   }



   @PostMapping("/addProduct")
   public String processOrder(@Valid Product product, BindingResult result, 
   @RequestParam("files") MultipartFile[] files, SessionStatus sessionStatus, Model model) 
   throws Exception{
    if (result.hasErrors()) {
        return "addProduct";


    }

    if (files != null && files.length > 0) {
        for (MultipartFile aFile : files){

            System.out.println("Saving file: " + aFile.getOriginalFilename());

            Product uploadFile = new Product();
            uploadFile.setFile(aFile.getBytes());
            service.save(uploadFile);
            model.addAttribute("product", service.findAll());

        }
    }

      return "product";
    }





   }
```

3. Product Repo

==================

```
  @Repository
  public interface ProductRepository extends CrudRepository<Product, Long> {

  Product findAllById(Long id);

 }
```

4. Add Product HTML

===================

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
 <head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">
 <title>Add Fixtures</title>
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
 <link rel="stylesheet" 
  href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" 
  integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" 
  crossorigin="anonymous">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.4.1/css/all.css" 
  integrity="sha384-5sAR7xN1Nv6T6+dT2mhtzEpVJvfS3NScPQTrOxhwjIuvcA67KV2R5Jz6kr4abQsz" 
 crossorigin="anonymous">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/shards.min.css">

 </head>
  <body>


  <h1> Add your Products Here</h1>

 <form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data"  th:action="@{/addProduct}" class="form- 
 container" id="aboutForm">
 <div class="col-lg-3" th:object="${category}">

<select class="form-control" id="category.id" name="category.id">
<option value="">Select Category</option>
    <option th:each="cat : ${list}"
            th:value="${cat.id}"
            th:text="${cat.id}+' : '+${cat.name}"></option>
 </select>
  </div>

  <div>

     <td><input type="file" name="fileUpload" size="50" /></td>
  </div>




 </form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `@RequestParam("files") MultipartFile[] files` should be: `@RequestParam("fileUpload") MultipartFile[] files` to match name of file input.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17185739/saving-byte-array-to-mysql

Comment: thats c# not java and its also quite old..